# How to counting frequency of values in a column on condition?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, counting

I have a csv file that has data as the following:

```
TaskId | Attr. 1 | Attr. 2 | Attr. 3
123        23     twothree     xyx
123        23     four         lor
456        23     four         pop
123        23     twothree     xyx
352        34     some         lkj
```

I want to produce a dictionary (or even just print) with attribute and frequency based on the task id.

Expected output:

```
For task id 123, 
23: 3 times

four: 1 times
twothree: 2 times

xyx: 2 times
lor: 1 time
```

I tried the following:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
from itertools import imap
from operator import  itemgetter

with open('task.csv') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)
    for row in data:
      if row[0] == '123':
         cn = Counter(imap(itemgetter(2), row))
         for t in cn.iteritems():
             print("{} appears {} times".format(*t))
```

But it did not work. In

```
Counter(imap(itemgetter(2), row))
```

instead of `row` and condition, I supplied `data` and it showed a particular column's items frequency correctly. But I want it based on a condition. How can this be done?

Comment: post the expected output

Comment: You might consider using groupby https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Posted the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` to create a nested dictionary:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

mystr = StringIO("""TaskId,Attr. 1,Attr. 2,Attr. 3
123,23,twothree,xyx
123,23,four,lor
456,23,four,pop
123,23,twothree,xyx
352,34,some,lkj""")

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

# replace mystr with open('file.csv', 'r')
with mystr as fin:
    for item in csv.DictReader(fin):
        d[int(item['TaskId'])][int(item['Attr. 1'])] += 1
        d[int(item['TaskId'])][item['Attr. 2']] += 1
        d[int(item['TaskId'])][item['Attr. 3']] += 1

print(d)

defaultdict({123: defaultdict(int, {23: 3, 'twothree': 2, 'xyx': 2,
                                    'four': 1, 'lor': 1}),
             352: defaultdict(int, {34: 1, 'some': 1, 'lkj': 1}),
             456: defaultdict(int, {23: 1, 'four': 1, 'pop': 1})})
```

Then iterate as you would a normal dictionary:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    print('TaskId: {0}'.format(k))
    for a, b in v.items():
        print('{0}: {1} times'.format(a, b))
```

Result:

```
TaskId: 123
23: 3 times
twothree: 2 times
xyx: 2 times
four: 1 times
lor: 1 times
TaskId: 456
23: 1 times
four: 1 times
pop: 1 times
TaskId: 352
34: 1 times
some: 1 times
lkj: 1 times
```

Comment: Worked great! what if I want to restrict that to the task '123' alone? ignore other task ids.

Comment: Just add an `if` condition, something like `for item in csv.DictReader(fin): | if int(item['TaskId']) == 123: | # do something`

Comment: a small follow up. What if I wanted to print out the attr. 1, 2, 3 as shown in the updated post? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use `d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)))` to add an extra level to your nested `defaultdict`. I'm rolling back your question, since there are already 3 hours and we shouldn't have a disjointed Q&A. If you get stuck, you can ask a new question (referencing this one).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Pandas, this can be done easily with a dictionary:

```
import csv
from tabulate import tabulate

uniquekeys = {}

with open('data') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)
    next(data, None)  # skip the headers
    for row in data:
        key = str(row[0]+":"+row[1])
        uniquekeys[key] = uniquekeys.get(key, 0) + 1
print(uniquekeys)
```

Alternatively, This could be done easily without python too:

```
cat data |awk  -F',' 'NR > 1{print $1":"$2}'|sort|uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be quicker to use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('task.csv') # open the file
df['count'] = 0 # add an extra column to count group value occurrences
counts = df.groupby(by = ['TaskId'], as_index = False, sort = False).count() # counts non blank values of the group
display(counts) # shows you the output
```

Comment: it seems like you are grouping all but I want "based on task id, attributes should be grouped"

Comment: Try and remove 'Attr. 1','Attr. 2','Attr. 3' from by = [list] and see if that what you want it?